# Изучение Java

Tags: java-ee, база-данных

Здраствуйте!Хотел бы начать изучение Java-EE,так как говорят,что он хорошо маштабируем.Я не имею опыта программирования на серверных языках,поэтому хочу спросить у вас какие-же материалы использовать для изучения серверного Java,а также материалы по базам данных.Не имею опыта программирования Java вообще?

Comment: профессиональные опердни на erlang! http://www.chicagoboss.org/
http://nitrogenproject.com/ *если говорить о масштабируемости*

Comment: @eicto а сколько там, в erlang'е байт на один символ идёт? (хотя я мог что-то и пропустить. Не слежу за ним).

Comment: я тоже не слежу, как-то занялся им но забросил ввиду нехватки времени, хотел на нем социальный проект закрутить реалтаймовый. прошарил суть и забросил, чикагобосс смотрел, а второй случайно недавно нашел, вроде даже прикольнее чикаги и развивается. *но с utf8 если что, там все в порядке*, а вообще там же строки не строки, а листы

Comment: *To understand why Erlang string handling is less efficient than a language like Perl, you need to know that each character uses 8 bytes of memory. That's right -- 8 bytes, not 8 bits! Erlang stores each character as a 32-bit integer, with a 32-bit pointer for the next item in the list (remember, strings are lists of characters.)* http://schemecookbook.org/Erlang/StringBasics

Comment: @eicto что-то ещё было про то, что данные масштабы относятся к 32-битным архитектурам. (на 64-битных вроде вдвое больше). Но утверждать не берусь -- могу и ошибаться.

Но представление строк в виде списка символов -- это не только erlang.

Comment: Холиварщики

Answer (score 1):

судя по вашему нынешнему и  [предыдущему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189968/js-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-javascript-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-php) вопросам, вы либо еще не знаете, чего хотите, либо хотите всего и сразу. Постарайтесь сосредоточиться на чем-то одном для начала. Для человека, практически не знакомого с программированием, изучать одновременно и Java и JavaScript и PHP вряд ли будет по силам. Более того, думать о масштабируемости вам пока рановато. 
 Ну а что касается материалов и всего такого, уж не обессудьте, зайдите в гугл - на этот вопрос ответ вы и там найдете - книг по Java навалом.

Comment: С php я решил покончить.Спросил я на будущее.

Comment: @Reyuzaki

     С php я решил покончить

Вы больше не будете писать на php, или никто больше не будет писать на php?

Comment: я на нём и не писал,я думал начать его изучать

Comment: Хватит разводить холивар